# Encoding trap for PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, security

Parsing the log after the use of a web vulnerability scanner, I found this

```
level Warning code 1366 message Incorrect string value: '\xDE~\xC7\x1FY\x00...' for column 'act_parametres' at row 1
```

The string is "\xDE~\xC7\x1FY\x00"

Here is a snippet to show my understanding

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('testsunitaires');
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8mb4');
mysql_query("set collation_connection='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");
mysql_query("set collation_database='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");
mysql_query("set collation_server='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'");

mysql_query('CREATE TABLE `encodage` (`chaine` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci');

$s = "\xDE~\xC7\x1FY\x00";
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO encodage SET chaine='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($s));
mysql_query($sql);
echo "$s => " . htmlentities($s, NULL, 'ISO-8859-1') . "\n";
echo "$s => " . htmlentities($s, NULL, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
echo mb_detect_encoding($s, 'auto', true) . "\n";

$req = mysql_query('SHOW WARNINGS');
while($a = mysql_fetch_array($req)) var_dump($a);
```

It output is

```
�~�Y => &THORN;~&Ccedil;Y
�~�Y => 

array(6) {
["Level"]=> string(7) "Warning"
["Code"]=> string(4) "1366"
["Message"]=> string(73) "Incorrect string value: '\xDE~\xC7\x1FY\x00' for column 'chaine' at row 1"
}
```

htmlentities() in ISO-8859-1 run fine, but not in UTF-8 (and my application is full UTF-8). mb_detect_encoding() is unable to parse the string.

This string is clearly a way to attack, but what is the best answer? Just trashing a string which encoding is not fine? Is there a way to clean the string? My goal is not having the Mysql warning at all, but not to miss an information from a badly configured browser which try to "talk" latin1 to an UTF-8 website.

Comment: perhaps addslashes()?

Comment: No, because there is no antislash in my string, this is just the hexadecimal notation, used here to put non printable character. And mysql_real_escape_string() is better for proofing the mysql calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8mb4');`. This informs the server that you're going to be sending UTF-8 to it, but it doesn't set the client-side `mysql_` extension to use UTF-8. This means `mysql_real_escape_string` escapes data according to the wrong character set, possibly leading to serious exploitable holes.

   Use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/mysql_set_charset) instead.
2. If a value is not valid UTF-8, then it's not valid UTF-8. You should not worry about "broken browsers". In practice there are none.* If your server receives data from the client in an unknown/broken encoding, you reject it. There's nothing else you can do with it. Check with [`mb_check_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_check_encoding) whether the data is encoded in the encoding you expect and throw a `400 Bad Request` error if it isn't. Also see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).
3. `mysql_` is deprecated, use mysqli or PDO.

<sub>* Some older IE versions tended to ignore the `accept-charset` declaration on forms under certain circumstances. This can be fixed by embedding a character which can only be encoded in one of the Unicode encodings in the form in a hidden field, say ✔.</sub>

Comment: I tried after your answer, mysql_set_charset() does not change anything, nor mysqli, but you are right about both. Your answer about handling bad encoded string help me more.

Comment: Yes, setting the charset properly wasn't really a solution to your problem, it was more a general important point while on the subject.